# Безопасно ли через функцию перезаписывать переменные в union?

Tags: c++

Пример кода:

```
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            bool is_small;
            u1 status;
            u1 arr[29];
            u1 a; // 1 байт
            u4 b; // 4 байта
            u4 c;
        } small_t;

        struct
        {
            bool is_small;
            u1 status;
            u1 * mem_ptr;
            u8 a; // 8 байт
            u8 b;
            u8 c;
        } big_t;
    };
```

И функция-метод записывающая данные в нужный вариант

```
    void Set( u8 a, u8 b, u8 c)
    {
        if ( a <= 29 )
        {
            small_t.is_small = true;
            small_t.a = a;
            small_t.b = b;
            small_t.c = c;
        } else {
            big_t.is_small = false;
            big_t.a = a;
            big_t.b = b;
            big_t.c = c;
        }
    }
```

Вопрос:
**Гарантирует ли стандарт, что вызванная выше функция с аргументами, полученных из union, даст им корректное временное расположение в стеке, а не испортит данные при чтении-записи в их альтернативную часть union.**

Пример вызова:

```
if( XX.small_t . is_small == true ) 
     XX . Set( XX.small_t . a + 9'999'999'999'999, 
               XX.small_t . b , 
               XX.small_t . c 
             );
// ======= Потенциальный inline до состояния ?? =======
// big_t . a = small_t . a + 9'999'999'999'999;
// big_t . b = small_t . b;
// big_t . c = small_t . c; // И тогда чеши пропало
```

**Дополнение/Уточнение:**

Будет ли код вызова функции выше равноценен коду ниже по стандарту ?:

```
auto a = XX.small_t . a; // Принудительно сохраняем 
auto b = XX.small_t . b; // значения в стек и используем
auto c = XX.small_t . c; // 

if( XX.small_t . is_small == true ) 
     XX . Set( a + 9'999'999'999'999, 
               b, 
               c
             );
```

Comment: `union` тут используется неправильно, в любой момент в нем может быть активно только одно поле, используйте `std:variant`. Ну клочки кода в вопросе в любом случае не компилируются.

Comment: @user7860670,   Функция за раз работает только с одним полем,  а в примере её вызова потенциально происходит пересечение с местом от куда читаются данные и куда записываются, и именно в этом и вопрос: Происходит ли в этом случае гарантированное копирование данных в стек перед записью или нет, согласно стандарту... ? А в случае компилирования, если честно я озадачен. а зачем данный пример нужно компилировать, если вопрос про стандарт ?

Comment: Если он не компилируется, то это значит, что он в принципе не рабочий и ни о каком копировании данных речи не идет. Ну а вообще да, аргументы же передаются по значению. Другое дело, что внутри функции может происходить обращение к неактивному полю - и это должно вас беспокоить в первую очередь.

Comment: @user7860670, Возможно мне нужно для вас внести пояснения:  1. Эти куски из 100% компилируемого кода.   2. Это написано кусками, чтобы не забивать вопрос ненужным по отношению к его сути, поэтому это больше условный код   3.  По моему мнению вы не на том сделали акцент, если вы можете дать комментарий по конкретно поставленному вопросу, вам цены не будет. Я сейчас немного дополню вопрос...

Comment: @user7860670, Я в первую очередь опасаюсь того, что компилятор может смачно заинлайнить и задосокращать до того, что может выйти так: "Читаю из А" -> "Пишу в Б" -> "Читаю из Б" -> "Пишу в Ц", и вот чтобы этого точно не могло произойти - На от этого стандарт гарантии даёт?

Comment: неправильно. Вынести надо переменную `bool is_small;` из `union`. Так как если вы не знаете каким элементом из `union` пользуетесь, то будет неопределённое поведение.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, хорошо что смотрите и замечаете мелочи, НО увы в этот раз - По стандарту: "для всех начальных одинаковых полей у структур в объединении - для них Гарантируется то, что они будут располагаться с одинаковым смещением в памяти и к ним безопасно обращаться из любой объединённой структуры" - не точная цитата, но суть такова.  И опять же, если вы не прочли комментарии выше, то убедительно прошу вас и всех  желающих помочь сведеньями, поставить акцент на строго поставленный вопрос, выделенный жирным.

Comment: Да, сперва читаем члены структуры `small_t`, инициализируем ими аргументы функции `Set`, т.е. делаем копии, затем эти копии служат инициализаторами для членов `small_t`, либо `big_t`. Являются ли структуры `small_t` и `big_t` членами одного объединения или нет в данном примере не важно. Ну... для компилятора-то важно: теперь он не может как попало «смачно инлайнить», но это уже проблемы компилятора. `не точная цитата, но суть такова.` — да, [class.mem.general / 25](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#25).

Comment: *"начальных одинаковых полей"* - это называется *common initial sequence* и поля `a` `b` `c` к ней не относятся.